# Android: Include all image resources in library

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I converted an android project app_1 (that contains some images resources in drawable folder and xml files in values folder) to a library and then published it to a maven repository as an aar.

So the library is an application so that i can launch it from another application. I included this library in my new project app_2 (app_2 contains just a button, when I press on the button I call that library and app_1 starts). when I call the library to start the app_1, I get a `NullPointerException` *for example on* `refreshIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.refresh_loading);` which is inside the library. So it's somehow when I generate the library, it doesn't include all image resources.

When it should include all project files ? when I convert the project to a library or when I publish to the Maven repository ? and why it doesn't include all files ?

How can I include all images and resources in the library so that the app_1 works with all the resources ?

Comment: is R.drawable pointing to app1 (see it in the imports)?

Comment: The app_1 works perfectly before I convert it to library and published it. so I think the answer is yes.
this code `refreshIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.refresh_loading);` is inside the app_1
app_2 has only one button to lanch the app_1

Comment: So, any suggestion please ?

Comment: @Lino Why you deleted your answer ? I explained in more details in the comment section !

Comment: my answer was not appropriate based on your requirements therefore I delete it. Stackoverflow must have high quality answers. Please, edit your question in order to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @Lino yes you're right. I just figure out what was the problem. I'm using a ViewStub in the library, and it's some how loads the resource slowly, so the application don't recognise the resources. I post another question about this subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671920/android-how-to-load-correctly-viewstub-in-library

Comment: feel free to post the answer and then accept it.

Comment: I figure out what cause the problem, not the solution, if you can please look at my other question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, it was a conflict between xml files name and attributes names. I just renamed all files/attributes which have same names.