# Android: How to load correctly ViewStub in library

Tags: java, android, view, viewstub

I created a library that uses ViewStub and integrated it to my project. When I run the application I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ViewStub must have a valid layoutResource` and just after `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference`.

I created another project without that library but the exact same viewstub and it worked.

So I guess the library loads the ViewStub slower the the application. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there any approach/solution to load the ViewStub from the library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I want to answer to my question to any one will face this problem in the future.

I just replaced the tag `<ViewStub>` by `<include>` and added the layout to it like this

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_layout_sml" />
```

and then I setup the visibility depending of my needs like this (for example to the actionBar):

```
public void setActionBarVisibility(boolean visible) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.include_action_bar);
    if (view != null) {
        if (visible) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone, somewhere.